# jQUery: to get all values in cells of each column in a table is being reset to 0 on colspan change

Tags: jquery

I have seen similar questions and they have brought me close to what I want to do but still not quite. Here is my html table (to which I really have no control... I don't understand the use of the second row but it is there anyway). The table class names are all autogenerated. The value in data-id is for groups and assured to be unique.

Here is my :  [Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/munkile/77j8nhmj/](https://jsfiddle.net/munkile/77j8nhmj/)

```
<table border="1" width="600px" id="table">

  <tr class="rpt_dg_row"><td colspan="3" class="rpt_dg_name" data-id="2">Start.2</td><td colspan="3" class="rpt_dg_name" data-id="3">Finish.3</td></tr>


  <tr class="rpt_ele_row">

  <td class="groupSubTotals rpt_ele_total g2" colspan="3" data-id="2">TotalStart2</td><td class="groupSubTotals rpt_ele_total g3" colspan="3" data-id="3 g3">TotalFinish3</td></tr>


  <tr class="rpt_details_row">
<th class="c2">Kids</th>
<th class="c2">Adults</th>
<th class="elementSubtTotals c2">Sum</th>
<th class="c3">Kids</th>
<th class="c3">Adults</th>
<th class="elementSubtTotals c3">Sum</th>
</tr>

 <tbody>
 <tr class="data">
 <td>1</td><td>2</td><td class="elementSubtTotals">3</td>
 <td>3</td><td>4</td><td class="elementSubtTotals">7</td></tr>
 <tr  class="data">
 <td>7</td><td>8</td><td class="elementSubtTotals">15</td>
 <td>9</td><td>10</td><td class="elementSubtTotals">19</td></tr>
 <tr  class="data">
 <td>25</td><td>26</td><td class="elementSubtTotals">51</td>
 <td>27</td><td>28</td><td class="elementSubtTotals">55</td>

 </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

Now I want is to get the values of the cells in proper grouping. The expected output is like this exactly

Group ID: 0 : 2 Start.2

SubGroup:0 : Kids Column Values: 1,7,25

SubGroup:1 : Adults Column Values: 2,8,26

SubGroup:2 : Sum Column Values: 3,15,51

Group ID: 1 : 3 Finish.3

SubGroup:0 : Kids Column Values: 3,9,27

SubGroup:1 : Adults Column Values: 4,10,28

SubGroup:2 : Sum Column Values: 7,19,55.

**Currently the Finish rows are return the same column as that of the Start block like this:**

Group ID: 1 : 3 Finish.3

SubGroup:0 : Kids Column Values: 1,7,25

SubGroup:1 : Adults Column Values: 2,8,26

SubGroup:2 : Sum Column Values: 3,15,51

As you can see, the top row is Group. The kids, adults...is subgroup. Then below is value for reach.

Here is my current script:

```
<script>
 var groupid=0;
$('#table tr .rpt_dg_name ').each(function (index, value) { 
 groupid=$(this).attr('data-id');
//loop all Groups
 document.write('<p>Group ID: ' + index + ' : ' +  $(this).attr('data-id') + " " + $(this).html() + '</p>'); 


   //get the Columns (kids, Adults etc) in that group:

        $('.c'+groupid).each(function (index2, value) { 

        document.write(' <p>SubGroup:' + index2 + ' : ' + $(this).html()); 

     //get the values of each in that column
               var values = [];

                $('#table tbody tr.data').each( function() {
                    values.push($(this).find('td').eq(index2).text());
                });

                  document.write(' <b> Column Values: ' + values + '</b></p>'); 

        });





    });





 </script>
```